# multipart/mixed request for netFramework 4.0 without BCL

Tags: c#, http, .net-4.0, httpwebrequest

The task: make multipart/mixed http request on net framework 4.0 without BCL. 
So it means "not to use System.Net.Http"

In the case of simple request i can use HttpWebRequest

```
WebResponse Send(byte[] data)
{
  var request = WebRequest.Create(uri);
  request.Method = "POST";
  request.ContentType = //....
  request.Headers.Add("myHeader","myHeaderContent);
  request.ContentLength = data.Length;

  using (var stream = request.GetRequestStream())
      stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
  return request.GetResponse();
}
```

But how can i make multipart/mixed to get request like this:

```
 POST http://google.com:9010/api/lalala HTTP/1.1
 Accept: application/json
 Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary="batch-1"
 Host: google.com:9010
 Vendor: vendor1
 Product: Test
 Product-Version: 1.0.0
 Plugin-Version: 0.0.1
 Content-Length: 208

 --batch-1
 Content-Type: application/http; msgtype=request
 POST /api/SubrequestPath/49f962b5wdd527 HTTP/1.1
 Host: google.com:9010

[{"jsonData":"data"}]

--batch-1--
 Content-Type: application/http; msgtype=request
 POST /api/Subreques2tPath/asdqwe HTTP/1.1
 Host: google.com:9010

[{"jsonData":"some other data"}]
```

Is there any HttpWebRequest capabilities, or open source lightweight packages?

Comment: I have to ask - why no BCL? Is this some sort of academic exercise to see how it can be done? [System.Net.Http](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Net.Http/) supports [.NET Standard 1.1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard), meaning it can run on virtually any OS or .NET platform that is still supported by Microsoft.

Comment: Net framework 4.0, old hardware and library conflicts

Answer (score 0):

I've done it with custom BCL-free http-client

**nugget**: TinyClient

**git**:    https://github.com/tmteam/TinyClient

Feel free to merge and request features.